# What is arctan (4/3)?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers

I'm refreshing my memory on sines, cosines, SOHCAHTOA, and writing complex numbers in polar form - I chose the complex number $3+4i$ to try and write it in polar form.  The modulus is easily computed to be $5$.  However, I'm having some trouble with computing its argument.  Based on drawing out the right triangle, thinking of $\tan(\theta)$, then the argument must be $\tan^{-1} (\frac{4}{3})$.

However, how do we actually *compute* this?

I don't think it's $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$ = $\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$, because that just seems weird and more like cotangent.

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before the trig functions, they come out in the right font so \tan(x) gives $\tan (x)$

Comment: You are correct that $\arctan(\theta)\neq (\tan(\theta))^{-1}$.  That is one of the unfortunate things of the commonly used notation.  People write things like $\sin^2(\theta)$ to mean $(\sin(\theta))^2$ as opposed to $\sin(\sin(\theta))$.  The $~^{-1}$ is often interpreted here as meaning the functional inverse as opposed to the multiplicative inverse.  This causes a great deal of confusion, especially among foreign students studying in a new environment.  For this reason, it is recommended to avoid the notation $\tan^{-1}$ at all costs and always write as $\arctan(\theta)$.

Comment: You are correct; $\arctan(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$ are notations for the inverse of the tangent function, not the reciprocal of $\tan(x)$, which is $\cot(x)$.

Comment: $\tan$ is what you get when you spend some time on the beach. As $\arctan$ is it's inverse, then $\arctan$ is what you get by unspending time on the beach.

Comment: @Voyska and cotangent is when the beach spends time on you?

Comment: @IanMiller Yes. And with this, we see that cotangent is obviously [russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_reversal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the $-1$ in $tan^{-1}\theta$ can be interpreted in two ways.

- As an inverse function - this is know as $\arctan\frac43$ and means the angle whose tangent is $\frac43$. For most values (including yours) there is no other way to write it short of writing a decimal approximation obtained from a calculator or similar. $\arctan\frac43\approx0.9272952180\cdots$
- As a reciprocal of a function - this is know as cotangent and you gave the correct definition, e.g. $\cot\theta=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$.

Usually the notation $\tan^{-1}\theta$ is reserved for the first meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Just a complement to other answers. At first, we have that $\arctan\frac{4}{3}$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$. Assuming $\arctan\frac{4}{3}\in\pi\mathbb{Q}$ we have that $z=\frac{3+4i}{5}$ is a primitive $q$-th root of unity, but its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by $5z^2-6z+5$, that is not a monic polynomial, hence is not a cyclotomic polynomial. So $\arctan\frac{4}{3}$ is not a "nice" angle. However, there are plenty of ways for approximating values of the arctangent function, for instance by exploiting continued fractions, the [(D'Aurizio)-Shafer-Fink inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753), [Machin-like formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Machin-LikeFormulas.html) or Taylor series. For instance, since

$$ \arctan(z)=\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{1}{2}(z-1)-\frac{1}{4} (z-1)^2+\frac{1}{12} (z-1)^3-\frac{1}{40} (z-1)^5+\frac{1}{48} (z-1)^6+O((z-1)^7)$$
we have:
$$ \arctan\frac{4}{3}\approx \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{24827}{174960} $$
and this approximation gives us the first five figures $\color{red}{0.92729}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\texttt{Newton-Rapson Method}$ yields a good approximation
$\displaystyle{~\left(~\mbox{starting from}\ 1 = \tan\left(\,{\pi \over 4}\,\right) ~\right)}$ with $\color{#f00}{\underline{3}}$ iterations:
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle{r_{0}} & \displaystyle{=} & \displaystyle{1}
\\[1mm]
\displaystyle{r_{n + 1}} & \displaystyle{=} & 
\displaystyle{r_{n} + {4 \over 3}\,\cos^{2}\left(\, r_{n}\,\right) -
{1 \over 2}\,\sin\left(\, 2r_{n}\,\right)\,,\qquad n \geq 0}
\end{array}\right. 
$$

---

$$
\begin{array}{cl}\hline
\displaystyle{n} & \displaystyle{\phantom{111}r_{n}}
\\ \hline
\displaystyle{0}   & \displaystyle{1.000000}
\\\displaystyle{1} & \displaystyle{0.934587}
\\
\displaystyle{2}   & \displaystyle{0.927366}
\\
\displaystyle{\color{#f00}{3}}   & \displaystyle{0.927295}
\\
\displaystyle{4}   & \displaystyle{\color{#f00}{0.927295}}
\\ \hline
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\qquad
\left\vert\,{\color{#f00}{0.927295} \over \arctan\left(\, 4/3\,\right)} - 1 \,\right\vert \times 100\ \% \approx 2.35 \times 10^{-5}\ \%
$$

> Note that $\displaystyle{{4 \over 3} > {\pi \over 4}}$. For this reason, our starting value was $\displaystyle{1 = \tan\left(\,{\pi \over 4}\,\right)}$.

Answer (score 1):

First off, its an angle in $\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$, and $\tan \theta = \dfrac{4}{3}$. It is often times that you are asked to find some thing like $\sin \theta $ for $0 < \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. With this in mind, you have:

$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)\implies \tan \theta = \dfrac{4}{3}=\dfrac{\dfrac{4}{5}}{\dfrac{3}{5}}\implies \sin \theta = \dfrac{4}{5},\cos \theta = \dfrac{3}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

Oh.  *NOW* I understand your question and confusion.

$\tan^{-1}(4/3)$ in this context means the *functional* inverse of tangent.  If $f$ is a function, such as $\tan$ is, then $f^{-1}$ means the function that maps the "output" of $f$ *back* to the input of $f$.  i.e.  If $f(x) = w$ then $f^{-1}(w) = x$.

So $\tan^{-1}(4/3)$ means "the angle, $x$, so that $\tan x = 4/3$".  $\tan^{-1}$ is often called the arctangent and is often written $\arctan 4/3$.

This is not to be confused with the *multiplicative* inverse, which is simply the fractional reciprical; $y^{-1} = \frac 1y$.  Unfortunately they are written the *exact same @#%!ing way*.

In context it should be clear.  In figuring the argument for $3 + 4i$ you want the angle so that $\tan x = 4/3$.  This is $\arctan 4/3$ or $\tan^{-1} 4/3$.  Obviously you do not figure this out by making a fraction out of $\frac 1{\tan 4/3}$.  You were right to be confused--- that wouldn't make any freaking sense.

So ... you are probably asking how *do* you calculate $\arctan 4/3$?  Well, there is no standard way.  You use tables or a calculator.  It's easy to see that it will also be the angle $x$ so that $\sin x = 4/5$ and $\cos x = 3/5$.

Whatever that is.

=====

How to compute?

$\frac {\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac 43$

So $\sin x = 4k;\cos x = 3k$ for some $k$ and so $(4^2k^2) + (3^2k^2)=1$ so $k = \pm 5$.

So $x = \sin^{-1} \pm 4/5 = \cos^{-1} \pm 3/5 = \tan^{-1} 4/3$.

How do you calculate those angle without a calculator?  You don't.  It is the base angle of a right triangle with base 3 and height 4.  whatever that is.